# Configuration file is not well-formed XML error in website why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-config

I have this in web config

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="web" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ttt\SQL2K12;initial catalog=test;User ID=sa;Password=1222;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   <add name="web" connectionString="data source=tttt\SQL2K12;initial catalog=test;User ID=sa; Password=555 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

but throws error:

**Configuration file is not well-formed XML**

why?

Comment: Your connection string has double quotes in the connection string.  Double quotes is a special character in xml and should be : U+0022 (34).  See wiki : https://www.google.com/search?q=wiki+html+xml+special+characters&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS752US753&oq=wiki+html+xml+special+characters&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64.14381j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8  You can use  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a double quote in the second Connection String.

Password=555 must be Password=555"

```
<add name="GalitosWebConnectionString" connectionString="data source=VLSAD0ISD\SQL2K12;initial catalog=test;User ID=sa; Password=555" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And it's better to not use the `sa` login for websites. If someone hacked the site they would also have full control over the DB.